# Pandas: Select columns based on row values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very large `pandas.Dataframe` and want to create a new Dataframe by selecting all columns where one row has a specific value.

```
        A     B     C     D    E 
Region  Nord  Süd   West  Nord Nord
value   2.3   1.2   4.2   0.5  1.3
value2  20    400   30    123  200
```

Now i want to create a new DataFrame with all columns where the row "Region" has the value "Nord".

How can it be done? The result should look like this:

```
        A     D    E
Region  Nord  Nord Nord
value   2.3   0.5  1.3
value2  20    123  200
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use first [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for select all rows (`:`) by mask compred selected row `Region` by another `loc`:

```
df = df.loc[:, df.loc['Region'] == 'Nord']
print (df)
           A     D     E
Region  Nord  Nord  Nord
value    2.3   0.5   1.3
value2    20   123   200
```

Better is crated `MultiIndex` by first row with original columns, then is possible select by [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html):

```
df.columns = [df.columns, df.iloc[0]]
df = df.iloc[1:].rename_axis((None, None), axis=1)
print (df)
          A    B    C    D    E
       Nord  Süd West Nord Nord
value   2.3  1.2  4.2  0.5  1.3
value2   20  400   30  123  200
```

---

```
print (df.xs('Nord', axis=1, level=1))
          A    D    E
value   2.3  0.5  1.3
value2   20  123  200


print (df.xs('Nord', axis=1, level=1, drop_level=False))
          A    D    E
       Nord Nord Nord
value   2.3  0.5  1.3
value2   20  123  200
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`df.T`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) with [`Series.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html):

```
In [312]: df.T[df.T.Region.eq('Nord')].T
Out[312]: 
           A     D     E
Region  Nord  Nord  Nord
value    2.3   0.5   1.3
value2    20   123   200
```